# Xamamarin Forms Essentials and Xamarin Forms Maps Find generic places like restaurants or bars

Tags: xamarin, maps

I have gotten Xamarin Essentials and Xamarin Maps to work.  I'm trying to figure out how to get them to do a search for generic things like restaurants or bars or hospitals or whaterve.  I can geocod and get location, use that to get address, but how do I get the places around the user?
I am still very new to Xamarin and doing this for a school project.

Comment: the Maps control itself doesn't do this.  You will need to use some search API to get the results, and then add them to the map yourself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search) shows: "There is no way to constrain Nearby Search or Text Search to only return specific fields. To keep from requesting (and paying for) data that you don't need, use a Find Place request instead."

And in this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place) you can understand how you can find restaurant or bars near the user using the `Find Place` with the `formatted_address`.

You can follow the link to create your request, and if you have any doubts, please, edit your question of what you did and we will help you. Have fun.